# InfoPath form dropdownlist value not order alphabetically after publish to SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have infopath form using different udcx connections in drop down list to display value from sharepoint list in Infopath drop down field. What i did in in Data connection i added existing udcx connection from SharePoint list and ordering value alphabetically. It all work fine until i publish the in to the SharePoint.

The existing publish method is using "Option Enable this form to be filled out by using a browser" and select Administrator-approved form template (Advanced) and choose the location where the Infopath file get publish. Then i upload the Published InfoPath path in Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Browser-enabled forms will only sort data connected to SharePoint lists by ID.

As a workaround, convert it to xml file, and sort data via xml method.

For more information, check the following blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/01/15/populating-form-data-from-sharepoint-list-views/